# Are there any simple electronic door locks available?

Tags: doors, lock

I have an office door I need to keep locked but allow easy access.
It doesn't have to be super secure, it has a proper deadlock for when we are closed, it just has to stop people casually walking in.
But everyone having to remember to lock it behind them with the key+deadlock is slow and inconvenient.

Any suggestions on a simple retrofit electronic lock? Low cost and easy to fit are priorities.

All the ones we looked at are built for Fort Knox. We just need something that moves a plunger out of the way for a few seconds with something like a garage door opener?

Comment: define 'low cost'.  Something like this is going to be in the $100-200 range.  There are radio controlled ones (although, check the features, many are deadbolts that you'd have to re-lock, defeating the purpose), and Schlage has a line that can be opened from anywhere via an iPhone app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need an electronic lock - you just need a lock that is always locked from the outside and yet allows exit from the inside.  Something commercial in nature is probably in order.  You probably won't find this at a home supply store, however.  You likely will need to consult a locksmith.

CORRECTION

[Link to Home Depot collection of storeroom locks.](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?keyword=storeroom%20lockset&selectedCatgry=SEARCH%20ALL&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&Ntpc=1&Ntpr=1)

You can find them at Home Depot.

Thanks to RSMoser for the proper name!

Comment: This type of lock is refered to as a "storeroom lockset". These locks operate the door with a key from the outside, and allow easy egress from the inside. They cannot be set to an un-locked position… they are always locked. Here is a link to the schlage website with the different types of locks and functions. http://professional.schlage.com/application_solutions/app_solutions_lockit.asp

Comment: Electronic was so we didn't have to manage keys for everyone. But just a latch type lock is probably going to be easiest

Comment: Ah well in that case Home Depot sells those for $100ish too.

Answer (score 0):

For a more high tech solution, have a look at [Lockitron](https://lockitron.com/preorder).

[image]

It fits over your existing deadbolt, and allows you to use your phone as the key.  It allows you to grant and revoke access as needed, and also lets you lock/unlock the door remotely.

<sub>*I've never used this product, nor am I associated with it in any way. I just think it's cool.*</sub>